# Uml: deployment diagram

Tags: android, api, uml, deployment-diagram

How do we show third party Api's in deployment diagram. To be specified is facebook sdk and twitter 4j separate web services that are entertaining my application?

Answer (score 0):

I would specify the API itself using components with interfaces. Interfaces have methods, that specify preciselly the API (RESTfull methods or whatever).

The components can be always assigned to nodes on a Deployment diagram, so you can do it if you need. The first idea is to have 2 nodes (one for FB/Twitter, another to host your system component), connected through a link stereotyped Internet.

Dependency flows from your system component, to corresponding interface(s).

Comment: That makes sense.I'll probably wait for a bit to see if someone else can suggest me something too and then I'll mark it as accepted answer.